# SearchController in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Я хочу использовать панель поиска в `tableView`. Я использую этот код для реализации поиска в `tableView`:

```
NSArray *searchResults;
NSMutableArray *_Array;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
    _Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5",@"6",@"7",@"8", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (self.searchController.isActive) {
        return [searchResults count];
    } else {
        return [_Array count];
    }
    }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }
 TableViewController *recipe = nil;
    if (self.searchController.isActive) {
        recipe = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        //recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSMutableArray *filtered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSString *value in _Array) if([value localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString: searchText]) [filtered addObject: value];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;
}
```

Но поиск не работает, когда пишу в строке поиска цифры. Почему это происходит? Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция filterContentForSearchText изменяет массив filtered, который далее нигде не используется.

Я думаю, что вам надо изменять массив searchResults.